# Sharepoint REST API update List Item unauthorized

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I am trying to update my list item using code shown in https://arcandotnet.wordpress.com/2015/04/01/sharepoint-2013-rest-services-using-c-and-the-httpclient-for-windows-store-apps/comment-page-1/#comment-133

but, I get unauthorized (401) error while posting request to url. Any idea why would i get that? The user i logged in has access to update information.

P.S i am trying to update sharepoint list item from ios app created in Xamarin Forms.

Comment: As @AlexChance asked, how are you authenticating? Could you capture and post the request and response headers for the request that got the 401 response?

Comment: How are you authenticating / logging in to the app?

Comment: Our sharepoint site is backed up with ADFS and azure, hence we are authenticating getting bearer token against adfs